# Derivation of Cycle Index

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, cyclic-groups, dihedral-groups, polya-counting-theory

I was going through the cycle index topic and I came across the cycle index for various types of groups. It is given that the cycle index for a cyclic group is
$$P_{C_n} (t_1 , \ldots ,t_n)= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d\mid n} \phi (d) t_d^{\frac{n}{d}},$$
Similarly the cycle index for a dihedral group with $2n$ elements is given as
$$P_{D_n}(x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n) = 
\frac{1}{2} P_{C_n} (x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n) + \left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{1}{2} \left( x_1x_2^{(n-1)/2} \right) \textrm{ when $n$ is odd } \\
\frac{1}{4} \left( x_2^{n/2} +x_1^2x_2^{(n-2)/2} \right)  \textrm{ when $n$ is even } 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Is there any way to derive those?

Comment: Riordan, J.: Introduction to Combinatorial Analysis

Comment: But that doesn't include the Derivation of the cycle index equation for dihedral groups

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index

Comment: Constantine, G. M.: Combinatorial Theory and Statistical Design. Wiley, 1987 . Chapter 6: Counting in the Presence of a Group https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/determine-cycle-index-dihedral-group-d2p-p-prime-number-chapter-14-problem-51e-solution-9780136020400-exc https://oeis.org/A212355 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376989/derivation-of-cycle-index

Comment: Cameron, P. J.; Semeraro, J.: The Cycle Polynomial of a Permutation Group. The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics 25 (2018) (1) P1.14. https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v25i1p14